# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' in Python reading from a csv

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?
I get a TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict

My target is to display the items in stock once and increase the counter of double products.
In this case orange: 2

```
enter code here

import argparse
import csv
from datetime import date

# Do not modify these lines
__winc_id__ = 'a2bc36ea784242e4989deb157d527ba0'
__human_name__ = 'superpy'

# Add your code after this line

# read requested input from file csv file
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("inputfile", help="insert name of the csv input file")

args = parser.parse_args()
with open(args.inputfile) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    hist = dict()

    for item in reader:
        if item in hist:
            hist[item]+=1
        else:
            hist[item]=1

        print(hist)

I use this .csv : 

enter code here

id,product_name,buy_date,buy_price,expiration_date
1, orange, 2020-01-01, 1, 2020-01-14
2, banana, 2020-01-01, 1, 2020-01-14
3, orange, 2020-01-01, 1, 2020-01-14
4, pizza, 2020-01-01, 1, 2020-01-14
```

Can you give me some advice how to fix this issue please?

Comment: `item` is a `dict`. You can't use a `dict` as key in a `dict`. Did you mean to use some value in the `dict` as key for the `dict`?

Comment: I would like to count the number of oranges from the csv in this case and put the counter to 2 peaces

Comment: So `hist[item['product_name']]`…?

Comment: Yes, but then I get the TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error when you try to use an unhashable key type when adding a key to a dictionary. here in the second dictionary hist you create a dictionary key using another dictionary.so you can fix it like this

```
for item in reader:
    if item["id"] in hist:
        hist[item["id"]]+=1
    else:
        hist[item["id"]]=1
```

Comment: `item in hist` also needs to be adjusted…

Comment: "item in hist also needs to be adjusted…" can you explain please: adjusted to what?

Comment: When I try this I still get the: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Yesss, I forgot to change that line. When you're increasing or decreasing your counters you're using an hashable keys (Id in my answer) so you cannot check for all the dictionary but need to check just for the key. The condition will be : if item["id"] in hist instead of what I kept

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps `pandas` can help to simplify things for you.

This code can be expanded to accept arguments from the argparser, where `args.inputfile` can be passed into the `pd.read_csv()` function.  For the sake of demonstration, I've kept the example simple.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the file into a DataFrame.
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/fruit.csv')

# Count values.
counts = df['product_name'].value_counts().reset_index().to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
for f, c in counts:
    print(f.strip(), c)

orange 2
pizza 1
banana 1
```

Edit:
The example has been edited so string output can be provided, rather than a DataFrame.

Comment: @Ruben80 - My pleasure.  Hope it might help to simplify things for you.